# Vector assests in android studio

Tags: android, vector, layout

How to use vector graphics in android studio?

How to change vector graphics color programmatically? Is it possible?

Can you guide me how vector graphic works in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cannot change the color of individual path at runtime.**

But you can be changed the color of the whole vector using setTint.

```
 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/vectorImageView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:tint="@color/my_nice_color"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_vector_drawable"
     android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

DrawableCompat.setTint(myImageView.getDrawable(),ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.another_nice_color));
```

[Read this setColorTint doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html#setColorFilter%28android.graphics.ColorFilter%29)

[Here is full document regarding vector assets. Read this.](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html)

Answer (score 0):

VectorDrawable is like any drawable in Android. I am giving a simple VectorDrawable xml file below. You may tweak the data in Android Studio and see how the shape (drawing) changes.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="600dp"
        android:height="600dp"
        android:viewportWidth="800.0"
        android:viewportHeight="800.0">

    <path
        android:pathData="M  162   8
        q    -07    00   -41    26
        q    -34    27   -50    64
        q    -25    59   -19   117
        q     07    70    53   121
        q     57    63   151    62
        q     87   -01   140   -66
        q     46   -55    48  -142
        q     01   -56   -34  -105
        q    -38   -52   -77   -70
        l    -29   -11
        q     16   -01    31   -02
        q     59   -01   119   -02     "

        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeColor="#f00f"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:strokeWidth="32"/>



</vector>
```

Also read the documentation for VectorDrawable and AnimatedVectorDrawable.

While you can do path morphing, animation of other kinds like trimPathEnd etc you cannot do other things like changing the strokeColor programmatically.

Hope this helps.